# How should I refactor code using Optional and ifPresent(...) to... not?

Tags: java, refactoring, option-type

I'm very new to Java. I'm faced with two classes, `FooRequest` and `BarRequest`. (Simplified for this question, of course.)

```
public class FooRequest {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private DateTime x;
    private DateTime y;
    private BigDecimal z;

    // ... and more members

    // ... getters and setters for each member
}
```

And the other class:

```
public class BarRequest {

    private Optional<DateTime> x;
    private Optional<DateTime> y;
    private Optional<BigDecimal> z;

    // ... getters and setters for each member
}
```

These were written by different people, one preferring null checks upon use, the other preferring `Optional`. But because `FooRequest` has many more members, is in widespread use, and completely covers all of `BarRequest`'s members, I'm tasked with getting rid of `BarRequest`, using the more popular `FooRequest` instead.

Now, at first I thought I might just "upgrade" `FooRequest`'s members (at least the 3 used by `BarRequest`) to `Optional<>`. However, this caused numerous compilation issues (basically, everywhere `FooRequest` was returned or used). I learned `Optional<T>` cannot drop-in replace `T`.

My team-lead confirmed it was not practical to keep `Optional<>`. To minimize changes, we'd want to rewrite any code previously using `Optional<>`. For example,

```
request.getDateBegin().ifPresent((dateBegin) -> {
  if (!dateBegin.equals(ad.startDate())) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Here's my attempt at converting this:

```
if (request.getDateBegin() != null) {
  DateTime dateBegin = request.getDateBegin();
  if (!dateBegin.equals(ad.startDate())) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is this correct? Am I missing something by simply doing a `null` comparison? Is there any way to use a lambda expression inside and avoid creating a `DateTime` temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (request.getDateBegin() != null) {
  DateTime dateBegin = request.getDateBegin();
  if (!dateBegin.equals(ad.startDate())) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

can be replaced with

```
Optional.ofNullable(request.getDateBegin())
            .filter(date -> !date.equals(ad.startDate()))
            .ifPresent(date -> {
                // ... whatever
            });
```

Comment: doesn't the filter give NPE if dateBegin is null?

Comment: @Turo nope, please see the source code of Optional.java

    `public Optional<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
        if (!isPresent())
            return this;
        else
            return predicate.test(value) ? this : empty();
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems to be that your attempt to convert the optional code into the typical imperative code is correct in terms of functionality. However, calling `request.getDateBegin()` twice is sub-optimal even if the call is not expensive it can be avoided.

Thus, I'd cache the result of `request.getDateBegin()` into a variable and operate on that.

If you're going to do this type of logic many times then you can put it into a method as such:

```
public boolean someMethodName(DateTime date, DateTime another){ 
     if(date != null && !date.equals(another)){
          // do logic
         return true; // successful
     }
     return false;  // not successful
}
```

the return type of the method is arguable so I'll leave that to you to decide.

Comment: I think the `DateTime` is from `joda-time`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what I should do with `BigDecimal`? Do I just compare it to `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead of `null`?

Comment: @AndrewCheong well if you're going to call an instance method upon a `BigDecimal` and there is a possibility that the reference referencing the `BigDecimal` can be `null` then it would be wise to perform a null check prior to operating on the instance. if however, that's not the case then you don't need a null check at all.